# Any easy way to subset my data set by time(1-5min),(2-6),(3-7)... in R?

Tags: r, subset

For example, my dataset name is "data", I have a variable(feature) name "Time", from 0 mins to 185 mins(consecutive). Also I have some other variables. I wanna analysis my data separately by Time "0min-5min", "1min to 6min", "2 to 7","3 to 8"... until the end.How can I do that? How can I label overlap time interval? I know the basic subset code in R, but I do not wanna import my data again and again, any easy way to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do post a [mcve], but it seems you may want `?cut` and `?split`

Comment: @RichardScriven Thank you for your suggestion, I did some revision for my question, It is more clear right now?

Comment: No, `dput(head(your_data))` would make it clear (`dput(droplevels(head(your_data)))` if you've got factors with lots of levels). You haven't shared what your data looks like in any reproducible way - `dput()` is copy-paste-able and makes sure the classes are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I can use "list" in R. And take them from the list, here is my code:

```
result  <- list()

maxMins  <- max(tph1nf5$Interval)
tph1nf5=tph1nf5[-1,]
for(i in seq(maxMins - 5))
{
  result[[i]]  <- tph1nf5[tph1nf5$Interval >= i & tph1nf5$Interval < i+5 ,]
  m_tph1nf5=conpl$new(result[[i]]$Step.length.in.mm)
  est_tph1nf5=estimate_xmin(m_tph1nf5)
  m_tph1nf5$setXmin(est_tph1nf5)
  print(est_tph1nf5$pars)
}
```